# How to send out quarterly reminders to risk owners for quarterly review?

Tags: administration

How to set up a task and send out emails at certain time, how to set up different groups of recipients.

Comment: Welcome to salesforce.stackexchange arjun. Adding more details to your question, like what you have already reseaeched on your own, will result in better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement look like "Email from a task". There is already an idea posted on [Idea exchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpAuAAK). It is not supported natively now. But you can achieve it by trigger and workflow action.

And for group - When sending email using Workflow action. In email action set-up process it is asked that whom the email will be sent, groups, users, creators, owner etc. there you can define recipient. Salesforce has native functionality to create public groups.

Comment: it is possible to send emails quarterly by using workflows?

Comment: It is possible by time dependent workflow but dates need to hard code which may no fit.

Comment: hi i got an another requirement, how to export lead activity history onto contact base on contact full name?